# SQL Server Stored Procedure Return value Assign to a Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to execute a SP inside another SP. Example below.
    declare @deal_1 as int
    declare @deal_2 as int

```
set @deal_1 = (EXEC [my second SP] @para1 = 'xxxxx' ) --this returns single value
set @deal_2 = (some other sub query)

select @deal_1, @deal_2
```

My question is above should return simple two column results but I can't get this to work. Unable to save due to errors or syntax issues.

Error I am getting is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'."

Comment: For subquery you can use the `Select ` syntax to set the variable.

Comment: Looks right at first glance. What is the exact syntax error?

Comment: What value does your `second sp` returns ? Try this syntax `EXEC @deal_1 = storedprocedureName 'InputParameter'`

Comment: Try `select @deal_1, @deal_2`. Did you really omit the `@` characters in your code?

Comment: I am getting "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'." . Issues is not with the select but executing and assign the value back to the variable. It always return int value

Answer (score 0):

Your select statement is unable to bind the columns `deal_1` and `deal_2` and there are no tables to bind to (i.e. no `FROM` clause in your select). Perhaps you meant to select the values of the parameters (note the `@` symbols)?

```
select @deal_1 as deal_1, @deal_2 as deal_2
```